# ElasticSearch aggregation on a script field

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, aggregation

I added to my elastic query a scripted filed, called "age", which is define like this:

```
  "script_fields" : {
    "age" : {
      "script" : "DateTime.now().year - doc['date_of_birth'].date.year"
    }
  }
```

Now, i also have other field for each person, called "myscore".
I'm trying to aggreagte on myscore, and create a sub-aggregation of age.
the result i should want to see is something like:

```
key: 25
buckets: [
     67,
     70,
     74
]
key: 62
buckets: [
    45
]
```

I added this aggregation:

```
{
    "myagg": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "myscore",
            "size": 1000,
            "order": {
                "_count": "desc"
            }
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "inner": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "age",
                    "size": 1000
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the inner buckets of the age returns empty (In the hits itself i can see the age field)...

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use script in aggregation:

```
"aggs" : {
"myagg": {
    "terms": {
        "field": "myscore",
        "order": {
            "_count": "desc"
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "group by age": {
            "terms": {
                "script": "DateTime.now().year - doc['dateCreated'].date.year"

            }
         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: that was the first thing I did, but becasue of the fact that I already retreive the "age" field from the query (so i use a script_field), i thought it will make sense to aggregate on it without writing the script all over again...

Comment: I am not sure if you can use scripted fields in aggregations or queries